Need help choosing microcontroller (for low-complexity task)
I am making an analog synthesizer, and part of the design will be a keyboard which scans and serializes key-press data, to send it to the main microcontroller (not the one in question).
This is a very low-complexity functionality that I originally drafted as less than 25 flip-flops, but it's obviously a waste of space and a trace-routing nightmare to have discrete flip-flops that are packaged in small powers of two. An FPGA will likely be overkill (unless someone can recommend a laughably small architecture if one exists).
I settled on implementing this digital design in a microcontroller, as software. However, I don't know how to choose a microcontroller that isn't an overkill for this application. I will need at most 16 GPIOs (but likely only about 8) and only a few dozen bytes of memory. A clock divider is welcome but not necessary as that can be implemented in software. Finally, I don't want to settle on anything slower than 1 MHz.
So far, I've had people recommend me AVRs, PICs, and even some saying that I should just go with a STM32C0 series since my main controller will be ARM Cortex based anyways. The problem with this is that I don't need so much fancy architecture or so much pins for such a simple functionality. I wanted to use an 8051, but people were criticizing the choice, even though apparently 8048's are used in billions of computer keyboards sold all over the world, likely because their small architecture fits the low-complexity and low-cost functionality.
So at this point I'm just running in circles and I have no idea what to choose.

Decide what is motivating your choice... There's no right answer to this question. In most cases, in low volume, your best bet is using something familiar.

@vicatcu I am not familiar with any family really, I just did general assembly programming in the past, so I'm a blank slate. The main controller will probably be an STM32, I'm being told that there are models with lower pin counts and simpler architecture, so I might use one of these for the lower-complexity function as well. I also like the ATtiny microcontrollers, I just learned about them. ChatGPT also made me aware of really tiny FPGA architectures. Now I just don't know how to choose between these options, and since I'm new at this, I don't really know what I want to be honest

You are implementing a synthesizer keyboard. You need a MCU that can match your specifications, and you don't seem to know what you want. The problem is not just scanning when a button push or release event is detected unless you want a simple keyboard. Normally each key has two buttons to detect how fast it  was pushed to send velocity data. The faster you scan the keyboard, the more steps you can have for velocity data.

There should be plenty of examples of keyboard scanning and midi output on the interwebs. It is a solved problem. You could choose the main micro to have USB host and just use an off the shelf keyboard that have midi over USB.

For close voters, the recommendation seems more general than wanting a specific device, considering they're even looking at the question of whether to use a micro or some flavour of programmable logic. Voting to reopen because describing the process to choose an appropriate device is always going to be valid, even if current end decisions may become obsolete.

Assuming you already have the development environment set up for the STM32 and are (or will  be) highly familiar with it, you can just use a lower end STM32 model (maybe a Cortex M0) and save a whole lot of time and hassles. Or even use the same model and ignore what you don't need, probably at some cost in parts cost but since you want a lot of I/O even that may not be so bad.
Not everything has to be optimized in favo[u]r of the hardware. The developer figures into the equation, especially at smaller quantities (and considering long-term maintenance).
There are still quite competitive 8051-core devices around such as the CH558 which can be programmed directly through a USB port bootloader (and runs a claimed 800+ times faster than an old-school 8051 and is less than $1. If you're writing in assembler then that could be pretty easy. And emerging technologies such as the 32-bit 144MHz CH32V203 (RISC-V) which will give you 37 claimed GPIO for about half a dollar in 100's. An Eclipse-based IDE is free, but you could also write your code in the rather pleasant RISC-V machine language. If you need an excuse to try something new out rather than a boring, practical and responsible solution...

A lower end STM32 is one of the top options at this point. I also just learned about ATtiny and they look like they are made for the type of low complexity functionality I'm looking for. Would that be a good option too? How should I choose between these two (ignoring the fact that I would already be using STM32 for the main controller)?

Also worth adding that yes, I am planning to write the code in assembly because it imitates the very low-level design anyways, there would be no point of writing it in C (I'm talking about the keyboard scanning and serializing of course, not the main microcontroller)

From your description an AVR with enough pins should be fine too. Other than ATMega, I've not used AVRs much, and only with 'C', but if I recall correctly, the machine language is more sensible than some (so HLLs run better).  One benefit of using STM32CubeIDE and MPLAB is that there are tools for configuring the device, which is probably half the work in your case. I already own an ATMEL-ICE (I guess now rebranded) but you may not so there might be some cost there.

It makes no sense to try writing the firmware in assembly. First of all, for a higher end ARM MCU, you get manufacturer C code for free which initializes the internal voltage regulators, PLLs and system clocks for the speed of your liking. It may take weeks to be able to figure out with the manual in which registers you need to write in which order to even make the CPU run at correct speed. For a low-end AVR, avr-gcc has long been good enough for tight code.

You could look for a reference design which implements a keyboard controller using a microcontroller, since that provides a reference schematic and software that gives you a starting point.
For example there is the TI TIDM-KEYBOARD which is a Keyboard Controller Using Low Power Microcontroller. From the features:


Supports standard matrix keyboards: this design shows an implementation using a 15x8 matrix but different keyboard layouts can be used
Independent of the communication interface: examples for USB and I2C are included
Supports multimedia keys
Can be implemented in practically any MSP430 platform: examples for MSP430F5529 and MSP430G2744 are included
Low power consumption


The question doesn't mention the interface between the keyboard scanner and the main microcontroller, but I2C will be simpler if both are on the same board rather than USB.
The MSP430 microcontrollers use a TI 16-bit RISC architecture, so should be suitable for low-complexity tasks. The software development tools are available for a no-cost license.

Thanks, I will now have a lot of things to look into, in order to decide how I'll implement it haha

You could look at CPLDs instead. The cheapest ones are generally cheaper than a micro, and they're far better geared up for scanning keyboards. Altera, Xilinx, and Lattice Semi are generally the names to look out for.
At the low end their specs and prices are pretty similar, so you might want to look at other things like easy availability of programming systems. Xilinx and Lattice are pretty good for that.

Thanks, I will look into that as well. I had the impression that even the cheapest CPLDs are on the order of $10 or so, but I probably didn't look deep enough

The CH32V003 is a very cheap and simple RISC-V microcontroller that might fit your needs.
